# Devise not obeying :path_names setting for sign_in route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to setup Devise 3.1.0 with Rails 4.0.0.

I have configured my router like so:

```
devise_for :users,
  :controllers => {
    :registrations => 'users/registrations',
    :sessions => 'users/sessions'
  },
  :path_names => {
    :sign_in => 'login',
    :sign_out => 'logout',
    :sign_up => 'new'
  }


        new_user_session GET    /users/login(.:format)         users/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/login(.:format)         users/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/logout(.:format)        users/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        users/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               users/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/new(.:format)           users/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          users/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)               users/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               users/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               users/registrations#destroy
```

I've also turned on scoped views, and overridden the default views and registration controller:

```
  # config/initializers/devise.rb
  config.scoped_views = true

  rails generate devise:views users

  # app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb
  #
  # NOTE: I created this class, so creating new users could only be done by authenticated users.
  #
  class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!
    prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!
    skip_before_filter :require_no_authentication
  end

  # app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb
  # (currently empty)
  class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  end
```

---

**The problem:**

Why devise is ignoring the `:path_names` settings above in some situations?

For example, this method will not use the `:sign_in` setting above, and returns an incorrect path:

```
new_session_path(resource_name)
=> /users/sign_in

resource_name
=> user
```

Whereas this method returns the correct path:

```
new_user_session_path
=> /users/login
```

The problem is, Devise internally uses the former method, and keeps redirecting to the wrong path when the user is not signed in.

Have I mis-configured something, or is Devise not working correctly?  Could this be a Rails 4 issue?

Comment: I actually think this is the intended behavior, since `devise_for` creates a bunch of routes for you automatically: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb#L337

Comment: If you wanted to remove those paths, you could always add `:skip => [:registrations]`, and only the `new_session_path(...)` method would be accessible in your views.

Comment: @farleyknight - yes, I know - and it's adding those routes correctly too, judging by the output of `rake routes`. However, calling `new_session_path(resource_name)` is producing the wrong output. If I've changed `sign_in` to `login` via `:path_names`, then it should be printing the url as `/users/login`, not `/users/sign_in`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue I was having was. (I'd still be interested to know, if anyone knows).

But I've found another way to express what I wanted with devise, and it seems to work OK:

```
devise_for :users,
  :controllers => {
    :registrations => 'users/registrations'
  },
  :path_names => {
    :sign_up => 'new'
  }, :skip => [:sessions]
  as :user do
    get '/users/login' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
    post '/users/login' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
    match '/users/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session,
      :via => Devise.mappings[:user].sign_out_via
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you trying to solve your question with the wrong feature, in this [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes) show you how to write another routes for devise, in my app I've recreated the routes with this:

```
  devise_scope :user do
    get '/cadastrar' => 'devise/registrations#new'
    get '/entrar' => 'devise/sessions#new'
    get '/editar' => 'devise/registrations#edit'
    delete '/sair' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end
```

I'm glad if work!